# Huge Memory consumption difference between x64 and x86 machines

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows-7-x64

I have developed an application written in **.NET 4.0/WPF/WCF**. This is a **Telecom application** which is connected with the big PBXes and provide the users to make call from the application. Lots of **event driven** programming has been used **(lots of Task Parallel Library, Asynchronous calls)** , so that any changes made on the hard phone reflects onto the application in real time etc…

The application works fine on high end machines.

My laptop configuration is RAM: 8GB, Processor: Intel i7, Logical CPU:8, OS: Windows 7 SP1 (x64)

On my laptop the application consumed memory is approximately **150 MB**. However, on a different machine where the configuration is RAM: 4gb (usable 2.9 GB), Dual core i3, Windows 7 SP1 (x86), the memory consumption is approximately **600 MB**. Can't figure out why such a difference!!!

Any pointers, please?

Comment: Use memory profiler, for example one from [Red Gate](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/) or [Jet Brains](http://www.jetbrains.com/dotmemory/)

Comment: My questions is more on the line of memory architecture x64 and x86...its after all the same application which is consuming 4 times memory on x86 machines.

Comment: Pointer heavy applications can get up to twice the memory usage. Are you talking about private memory or what? In any case, there usually isn't much of a reason for concern, unless your system memory is deficient - both Windows and .NET will happily release a lot of the "used" memory if the system is put under memory pressure. Profiling is a common first step - you can use the free CLRProfiler to see what's different between the two processes, and of course tools like VMMap to see diferences between virtual memory usage.

Comment: I am not even convinced that the OP has gathered accurate metrics. The OP does not talk about `GC.Collect` so I suspect that actual memory consumption might be fine.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to figure out if this is actually a problem.

.NET garbage collection tries hard to stay out of the way.  One of the things it does as a result is to avoid cleaning when no cleaning is needed.  If you have 2.9 GB unused, and only 600MB used by this process, the garbage collector may simply not care yet.

So, pull out the memory profilers and find out if you really have a problem or not.

Comment: Ok there may be a confusion... 2.9gb is **total available memory** out of **4gb on x86** Windows 7 OS. CPU utilization is not a problem its fine but the memory which slows the system; when I kill the application the memory frees by almost 18-20 %.

Comment: I am going through the link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/cc163715.aspx may be some answers are there.